# keil debugging mode doesn't work properly

Tags: hex

I'm trying to biuld a counter with stm32f103c8t6 and watch counting variable value using keil uvision debugger.
when i press the button, the variable value change, but after that the variable value change to zero and doesn't save .
I don't know what to do.
i think that keil write code on micro repeatedly and so the variable value doesn't change or doest let to micro to run delay to let led blink .

I write led blinking code and run it on micro and it work properly, but when I'm useing debuging to test this code, code doesn't work and led doesn't blinking and led is always on.